# Swift stackview add subview in center

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, stackview

I use this code for view nib to stackview

```
for index in 0..<4 {
    let view = CategoryClass.createMyClassView()
    view.myLabel.text = "Hello World!"
    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
}
```

And I get below image :

[image]

But I want to add subview by category.xib height ( 40px per view ) not fill.

And set in center of parent

Like below :

[image]

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: check the constraints of stackView please upload screenshot

Comment: Add height constraint for myLabel before adding to stackview

Comment: @sanjaykmwt i added screen shot of stackview

Comment: @RajeshKumarR not working for me

Comment: Try to add height constraint for stack view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please add Four label in Xib and after put in stackView and give spacing like 5, 10, 20 whatever you like 

Please check screenshot and let me know if u have any problem related stackview i will help you
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the top and bottom constraints of the stackView. Or you can delete any one and make the other constraint in **greater than or equal to** form
This will solve your problem